# Convert array index into a string?

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$errors[] = "Field not correct.";
```

I want return a json encode as: `{"errore" : "Field not correct"}` this is my code for do it:

```
return json_encode(array("error" => serialize($errors)));
```

but i get:

```
{
    "error": "a:1:{i:0;s:21:"Field not correct.";}"
}
```

how I can avoid the symbol `a:1:{i:0;s:21`  in the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `serialize` and only use `json_encode`.

```
$errors[] = "Field not correct.";
return json_encode(["error" => $errors]);
```

Note that this will have an *array* of errors, due to the way you are putting your error string into an array first.

If you only have a single error message, then don't use a `$errors` array.

```
$error = "Field not correct.";
return json_encode(["error" => $error]);
```

See here for both options: https://3v4l.org/JQVNA

Comment: thanks for the hint, just a question, why you have inserted the bracket `[` into `json_encode` ?

Comment: @Sandokan that's just the shorthand notation for arrays. it's the exact same as `array(` just shorter. i prefer it.

Comment: Sure I'm waiting the time of stackoverflow that allow me to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Just don't call `serialize` (which converts it to a PHP-specific string format).

Pass your PHP data structure to `json_encode` (which converts it to a standard string format) directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you could have multiple errors, but the format you provice only supports one error. `$errors` could have multiple entries. `{"errore" : ".."}` only could keep one message.

So you have some choices:

Only use the first error in `$errors`

```
 return json_encode(array("error" => $errors[0]));
```

Combine the errors with some function (i.e. `join`)

```
 return json_encode(array("error" => join(',', $errors)));
```

Change the format of your output to support multiple errors

```
return json_encode(array("error" => $errors));
```

which would result a json string like

```
{"errore" : ['msg', ...]}
```